# Chrome ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, browser, cname

I registered a **CNAME record** from *mydomain.futbol* to a **godaddy domain**
I can correctly ping the new address, the trace route reaches godaddy servers.
I can not display the page on my browser, I get this error:

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I tried to clean the browser DNS cache and to flush the operating system dns.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: `I can correctly ping the new address` - do use use hostname when you ping? `the trace route reaches godaddy servers` - ok. Is go daddy correct destination for this traceroute?

Comment: Yes I can ping the hostname that reaches the godaddy servers. (so the CNAME is right configured)

Comment: OK. Then see this [question](http://superuser.com/q/719559/238539). It is about same topic and it is answered.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried but it is not working. Can .futbol be the problem? It is a "new kind" of top domain level.