# DNS works on one WiFi network, not on another

Tags: dns

I have tried all the suggestions in this post (ie clearing host cache): [Why can't Chrome load a web page? ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED](https://superuser.com/questions/719559/why-cant-chrome-load-a-web-page-err-name-not-resolved)

On one one WiFi network the DNS resolution works:

[image]

But on another it does not:

[image]

I believe it has been well over 24 hours:

[image]

Any ideas what is wrong? It also doesn't work on my phone LTE or Stanford Residences WiFi. The results are the same in all browsers so it has nothing to do with the browsers.

Comment: On the connections it isn't working on.  Can you ping the domain?  Have you tried to configure the non-working connections, to use the same DNS servers, as the working connection uses?

Comment: I did ping on the connections it isn't working on. I got "could not connect". I can give you the exact output of ping when I get back to that connection.

Comment: Now on Stanford Residences there is no error. I believe the solution is to wait 48-72 hours. Should I post that as the answer?