# Can't acces to a MIT webpage (Chrome and Firefox)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cache

I'm trying to download a PDF about wind energy ([Link](http://web.mit.edu/windenergy/windweek/Presentations/Wind%20Energy%20101.pdf)) from a Massachusetts Institute of Technology webpage but Chrome throw me this.

> web.mit.edu's server DNS addres could not be found. 
>   ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

However, a friend of mine was able to access and download this PDF so I suppose that the problem is here. I've already tried flushing [link](https://superuser.com/questions/719559/why-cant-chrome-load-a-web-page-err-name-not-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

You can view the document from [here](http://viewppt.com/docs/web__mit__edu--windenergy--windweek--Presentations--Wind%20Energy%20101__pdf.html).